# How to subscribe to multiple recurring payment plans with PayPal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

For instance there are 100 houses and I want to set the same subscribed rent plan of $50 for all houses at once.

Answer (score 1):

[PayPal Subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/) allows you to create a plan with `quantity_supported: true`. See the Plans API reference here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#plans

Then when creating a Subscription with that Plan, pass 100 (for your example) as the quantity.